# windows 10: how to schedule a task to start only when the computer sleep

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

The task is scheduled to start at a specific time, but it should not start if the computer is waked. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [Idle Conditions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721902(v=ws.11).aspx).

> You can set a condition that tells the task to run only if the computer is in an idle state for a specific amount of time when a trigger is activated.

You can add this to the time trigger and it should work the way you want it.

Comment: It does not work. The task still run when the computer plays a sound. Am I missing something?

Comment: maybe you should read into what the Idle Status actually is and then rewrite your scenario